# CreateWindow API is not working on VS2015

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

We are using `CreateWindow()` API which was working correctly on VS2012 before upgrading to VS2015. After upgrading to VS2015 `CreateWindow` API is returning null HWND.

We are calling `AtlAxWinInit()` before `CreateWindow()` API as shown below.

Eg:

```
// Code on VS2012 which is working correctly and failing on VS2015.

CreateControl()
{
    BOOL res = AtlAxWinInit();         // successfully return true..
    // Below API successfully return HWND on VS2012 level.
    HWND hwndChild =   CreateWindow(_T("AtlAxWin110"),
                                    _T("test"),
                                    WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,
                                    0,0,0,0,
                                    hwnd,NULL,
                                    ::GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                                    NULL);
}
```

As per VS2015 we changed class name to "AtlAxWin140" still API is failing.

```
CreateControl()
{
    BOOL res = AtlAxWinInit();         // successfully return true..
    // For VS2015 we changed class name to "AtlAxWin140" still API is returning null HWND.
    HWND hwndChild =   CreateWindow(_T("AtlAxWin140"),
                                    _T("test"),
                                    WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,
                                    0,0,0,0,
                                    hwnd,NULL,
                                    ::GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                                    NULL);
}
```

I also checked `GetLastError()` after `CreateWindow` calll; it is returning

> "Class is not registered".

Could you please help me to resolve this..

Thanks..

Comment: It is in fact "AtlAxWin140", better to use the ATLAXWIN_CLASS macro.  Not many conceivable ways this can go wrong, other than still #including the old VS2012 .h files.  Use the /showIncludes compile option so you can see more.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried by using ATLAXWIN_CLASS macro still i am getting same error. I have included below headers in my file(shown all includes):                                                               #include <assert.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <exdisp.h>
#include <exdispid.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <atldef.h>
#include <atliface.h>
#include <atlhost.h>
#include <afxmt.h>

Comment: Surest fix is to register your own class.

Comment: A question for you. What do you think that *"Class is not registered"* indicates?

Comment: If we see implementation of AtlAxWinInit() API. This method internally register "AtlAxWin140" class. As per my understanding if this method registers class, no need to register class again.. Same code is working on VS2012 if we change class name to "AtlAxWin110".

Comment: @DnyandevPulwale - if method successfully registered class (and not unregister latter) - it of course not need register again. but in this case you not got *Class is not registered* error. this mean that you routine, which register class not called (or by some conditional not call register for this class), or register class fail (say input structure wrong initialized), or you use different name for class. you need debug for se exactly what happens.

Comment: Is `CreateControl()` called by a DLL function? Because `::GetModuleHandle(NULL)` would be wrong then.

Comment: Explanation for @zett42 's comment: [What is the HINSTANCE passed to CreateWindow and RegisterClass used for?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873). If that is indeed the case, you'll find a solution here: [Accessing the current module’s HINSTANCE from a static library](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041025-00/?p=37483).

Comment: I am getting 1407 error code from CreateWindow API. I checked error code using GetLastError() API. 1407 means ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS :Cannot find window class.